# Iterating in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I'm trying to make a model where I make a copy of 'geodatabase A' to another location as 'geodatabase B', delete all of the datasets within, and create new datasets for geodatabase B. The reason I'm copying a particular geodatabase (geodatabase A) is because it contains all the domains I need for geodatabase B. However, I want to delete the datasets once it's copied so that I can reassign the spacial reference. When I put the copy tool and the iterate datasets together in one model, it iterated the copy function as well, making the model go infinitely. So now I'm thinking I need to put the iteration as a submodel. However, I'm not sure how I can reference the input for the iteration, as the input doesn't exist yet.

Can someone help me or let me know a better way to do this?

[image]

Comment: It may be more efficient to export your geodatabase schema to a xml workspace document and use that to apply domains to new geodatabases. More details here: https://community.esri.com/thread/124092 and http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/exporting-a-geodatabase-schema-to-an-xml-workspace-document.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Expose "New geodatabase" in your delete datasets model as a parameter.
2. Drag that model into your master model, which you appear to have called "Model 1".
3. Connect the output of copy to the embedded sub-model.
4. Et Voila!

Comment: Thank you! I was able to do number 1 & 2 but not 3. When I bring in the copy too, it already comes with an output bubble that says 'Output Data Element'. How can I equate the Output Data Element with the New Geodatabase parameter?

Comment: Just select the blue input to your sub-model and delete it then connect the output of copy and you will see the option to connect to the correct parameter.